# How to migrate request-promise to axios or fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, axios, xmlhttprequest

I want to code a app with React-Native which loads JSON-files from a website with cookie-authentication.
For testing I tried it in a normal JS-file without React-native and with request-promise.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const request = require("request-promise").defaults({ jar: true });

async function main() {
  var incodeHeader = "";
  var incodeToken = "";

  try {
    const loginResult = await request.post("https://somepage/login.php", {
      form: {
        client: "XXX",
        login: "username",
        password: "password",
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  incodeHeader = getIncodeHeader();
  incodeToken = getIncodeToken();

  const data = await request.post("https://somepage/load.json", {
    headers: {
      [incodeHeader]: incodeToken,
    },

    form: {
      max: "10",
    },
  });

  fs.writeFileSync("data.json", data);
}

main();
```

This worked well, so I wanted to use this method in my App, but I couldn't find a way to use request-promise in React-Native so I decided to use axios.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const qs = require("qs");
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

async function main() {
  const data = {
    client: "XXX",
    login: "username",
    password: "password",
  };

  await axios
    .post("https://somepage/login.php", qs.stringify(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  const incodeHeader = getIncodeHeader();
  const incodeToken = getIncodetoken();

  await axios
    .get(
      "https://somepage/load.json",
      { data: { max: "5" } },
      {
        headers: {
          [incodeHeader]: incodeToken,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((respone) => console.log(respone))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

main();
```

But in this code not even the login works and I really don't know why. Can somebody tell me how to do this right, or can tell me another solution which works in React-Native?

Comment: Just a side note, you might want to get yourself acquainted with SOLID principles.

Comment: If you use `await`, drop all the `.then()`. Use the old Promise-like syntax (`.then()`) or the new `async/await`, not both together. Also, please [define "it's not working"](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)? Did you try to `console.log()` stuff, to see if your function is being called and if data is right? Any errors in the console? Etc.

Comment: I don't think you need the `qs.stringify()`. And I am not really sure about the `[incodeHeader]: incodeToken,` part. Please read [the docs](https://github.com/axios/axios) again.

Comment: Ha, formerly you were calling `request.post` and now you are calling `axios.get`. It's supposed to be `axios.post`. You can't send a data object with GET.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't know why you're stringifying the request body in the first request, axios already handle this, you can pass just the `data` object, maybe it's the solution for your problem.

Second (just a tip). Create a helper object to make http requests and do not instance axios directly, so then, you can change the http request handler in an easy way instead changing it on each file, one day you probably will need to do this if you want to keep your app updated.

Third, don't mix `await` and `then`, choose:

```
try {
  const result = await action();

  // ...
} catch (err) {
  // ...
}
```

or

```
action()
  .then((result) => {
    // ...
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // ...
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

change `await axios.get` to `await axios.post`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 